# Error running a program compiled on a different PC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

I have written a small program on a PC in VS Code. I have taken 2 files which are source.cpp and exe file to another PC by USB.

At first I got some DLL errors, but I solved these problems. However, I am still getting an error that "Application unable to start correctly error 0x000007b".

I have tried every solution on the internet but the problem still exists. Both PCs are x64. Is there any way to run a program which is taken to another PC?

Comment: First, make sure both computers are up to date with **Windows 10** May 2021 Update ("21H1", 10.0.19043).

Comment: what dlls caused problems and how did you solve these?

Comment: "Both PCs are x64." Good, but are both _operating systems_ x64 as well? And all DLLs that you randomly copied in your attempts to solve the DLL problems?

Comment: @Eljay it may be true, I will check it, thanks!

Comment: Second, it will be very helpful if you share with us the compile/link command used to compile the source.cpp to make the exe.  (Because if you compiled in DEBUG mode, the exe isn't generally portable.)  Third, did you install the [redistributable package](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-the-application-is-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc00007b-error/#e) onto the other PC?

Comment: @Sebphil 3 dlls were lack so i downloaded them which are "VCRUNTIME140D.dll", "ucrtbased.dll", "msvcp140d.dll".

Comment: @Thomas yes both pc are operating systems x64. Exactly what I have done to solve dll problem download and copy paste.

Comment: Those are dlls for debug-mode... Never copy and paste dlls (or download them directly)! Compile your program in release mode (x64)... they shouldn't be required to run your executable on another system.

Comment: @Eljay yes, I did. I installed redistributable package 2019 and x64 distribution.  For your 2nd reply, I used an extention of Vs Code which related to MinGW-w64. However, I took source code as well the folder in 2nd pc.

Comment: @Sebphil thank you so much, after compiling release mode, it worked.